# При открытии браузера Google Chrome открывается браузер без расширений (selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Имеется Google Chrome Portable (портативный), который расположен в папке "**1_1**".
На нём установлено расширение: `Site Geo IP Locator` (скриншот):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске ПРОЕКТ 1 на C# (с использованием `selenium`, `WebDriver.dll`, chromedriver.exe) открывается браузер `Google Chrome Portable`, в котором установлено только расширение "`Chrome Automation Extension`", которое я не устанавливал.

Сценарий проекта:

1. открыть браузер Google Chrome Portable, который находится по пути GoogleChromePortable_1.exe;
2. открыть поисковик (google.com);
3. ввести слово для поиска;
4. осуществить поиск;

**ВОПРОС**:
1. Почему когда запускаем ПРОЕКТ 1 на C#, который по сценарию открывает браузер Google Chrome Portable, в браузере установлено только расширение "Chrome Automation Extension", которое я не устанавливал, а установленного расширения нет?

См. скриншот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ.** 
1. Код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
//****// 
using System.Diagnostics;
//****// 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        IWebDriver Browser;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions co = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
            //****// 

            co.BinaryLocation = @ "c:\soft\UD\GoogleChromePortable\1_1\GoogleChromePortable_1.exe";

            //****// 
            Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(co);
            Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("google.com");

            IWebElement SearchInput = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
            SearchInput.SendKeys("проект домов" + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `AddExtension`

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions co = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
co.BinaryLocation = @"c:\soft\UD\GoogleChromePortable\1_1\GoogleChromePortable_1.exe";
co.AddExtension(Path.GetFullPath("local/path/to/Site-Geo-IP-Locator_v1.2.1.crx"));

Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(co);
```

Скачать файл `.crx` можно через этот сервис: http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/

Comment: Что-то не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не срабатывает.  Прилагаю скриншот http://prntscr.com/c9i1r0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
//****//
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.IO;
//****//

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IWebDriver Browser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions co = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
        co.BinaryLocation = @"c:\soft\UD\GoogleChromePortable\1_1\GoogleChromePortable_1.exe";
        co.AddExtension(Path.GetFullPath("c:\soft\UD\GoogleChromePortable\1_1\profil\SiteGeoIPLocator\SiteGeoIPLocator.crx));

        Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(co);

        Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

        IWebElement SearchInput = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
        SearchInput.SendKeys("проект домов" + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}